# How to shift google map control on map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application i am using google map api v3 of google. I want to shift my map control when i open my address panel but map control is not shift when i try to  redraw controls on map. i want shift all map control like google map. For demo purpose please go to https://maps.google.co.in/ and search for hotel or anything then hide the side address panel. There you can see map controls always shift form edge to panel edge. I want to shift my map controls like this. Please provide any solution for move my control on map like google map.

Comment: Are you talking about the address panel slide to the side, the map gets wider and the controls move to the side?

Comment: For see my application please go to my application and continue as a guest and click on store locator link. There you can see google map than you can search a valid US zip code like 98124. There you can see address panel. When address panel is open map controls always behind that panel. I want to shift my map control with that panel like google map. Link : https://pay.evolvemoney.com/opp/

Comment: Yes.. you are right .. I want to shift my  map controls like that. As you see in google map. Please go to my provided link there you can see scenario what i am talking about.. Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: I don't think Google moves the controls, they change the width of the map and somehow pan the map instantly to the same position. Don't know how though.

Comment: No, Google moves the control not change the width map because map always look static. In general scenario if we re-size the map without loading map. It always show blank area.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is give your map a bit of `margin` on the left and when you close your address panel remove that `margin` and update the map.

So something like:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height:400px; margin-left:100px"></div>
<a href="#">Expand</a>

<script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0));
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.latLng(40.736852, -74.002748));
    map.setZoom(12);

    var o = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    o.draw = function() {}
    o.setMap(map);

    $('a').on('click', function(){
        // Remove margin
        $('#map').css('marginLeft','0px');
        // Get current position in pixels on the map
        var current = o.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(map.getCenter());
        // Set position to current - to margin-left.
        map.setCenter(o.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng({x:current.x - 100, y:current.y}));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment.. But we are putting some pin on map. If we reload the map means it loss previous status.

Comment: Is is not reloading, it is just setting the center a little bit further to the right. You won't loose anything

Comment: Okey...I can try and get you back.. thanks a lot man..!! If you have any other solution please provide me..